# Retrieve the screen's resolution of a window with Applescript

Tags: applescript

In case of several screens, is there a way to know on which screen an application's document is displayed?

For example, in Photoshop, I'am able to retrieve the position of document's windows with:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Adobe Photoshop CS6"
    ---------- document's window list
    set docsWinList to {}
    copy (the windows whose name ≠ "") to docsWinList
    set docsWinCount to (count of docsWinList)
    if (docsWinCount < 1) then return -- no opened documents

    ---------- position of the first document's window
    tell item 1 of docsWinList
        set hvCoords to position -- list with 2 items : h and v coords
    end tell
end tell
```

But these coords are **absolute** to all the screens (and can be negative).

On the other hand, I'm able to know all the screens's resolution with a script found here:

```
on getScreensResolution()
    set screensSizes to {}
    repeat with p in paragraphs of (do shell script "system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | awk '/Resolution:/{ printf \"%s %s\\n\", $2, $4 }'")
        set screensSizes to screensSizes & {{word 1 of p as number, word 2 of p as number}}
    end repeat
    # `screensSizes` now contains a list of size lists;
    # e.g., with 2 displays, something like {{2560, 1440}, {1920, 1200}}

    return screensSizes
end getScreensResolution
```

As the window's coords previously found can be negative, depending if the window is displayed on a second screen and this screen is physically located at the left of the main screen (defined by the OS), I would like to know the resolution of this document window's screen.

I'm not sure it's possible, or maybe it involves lots of calculation.

Answer (score 0):

*(In addition to your thoughts I'd like to remark that windows can have negative location values even if you only use ONE screen: just move any window beyond the left border of your screen …)*

If you got exactly two screens your question is quite easily answered.
Starting from your 1st script just add this line …

`if (item 1 of (size of window 1 as list)) * -1 > (item 1 of hvCoords)) then display dialog "Your window is located on a screen left of your active one."`

– "if …then" decides if "window 1"s negative x-value is larger than its factual width
– "display dialog" is a placeholder/feedback for whatever code you plan to add …

For example: if a window sized 750x400px returns an x value of -1,122 the above line will calculate
`750* -1 > -1,122  => -750 > -1,122 => true => window located on left-screen.`

This code assumes that a window will be displayed on your left screen *ONLY if it's fully transferred* there.
In case windows are already transferred once "half of their size" is moved, adapt above code thus:

`(item 1 of (size of window 1 as list)) *`**`-1/2`**
                                                                                     =====
(You'd need your 2nd script's values only if you use more than 2 screens.)